# FOREIGN KEY doesn't complete column after INSERT (PHP)

Tags: php, mysql

I have 2 tables. In the first i have id_user (that is primary key),username,name,password and in the second i have id_post(primary key),post,username,view,id(foreign key that references id_user). 
After i use the query:

```
$query ="INSERT INTO posts (username,post,view) VALUES ('$username','$postare','$isprivate')";
```

It completes my column id with NULL. I want in the column id to have the id_user of the user that make the query.Not NULL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to look up the value to get that in the data.  So, using your construct the query would look something like this:

```
insert into posts (userid, post, view) 
    select u.userid, $postare, $isprivate
    from users u
    where u.username = '$username';
```

Notes:

- Do not store both `userid` and `username` in the `posts` table.  Only store the `username` in the `users` table and use `userid` to get the name when you need it.
- Don't munge your query string by putting values directly in it.  Learn to use parameterized queries.
- `view` is a really bad name for a column, because it is an SQL keyword.